# Validation of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I am doing an application for world cup. And in the model I want add a validation:
A single team can not play two games on the same date. The date is the field mathdate and the teams are local_team_id and visiting_team_id.I tried with How could I do that validation in the model?

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :mathdate, :presence => true
validate :mydate_is_date?
validates :stage, :presence => true
validates :stage, numericality: {only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 1, less_than_or_equal_to: 6}
validates :state, :presence => true
validates :state, numericality: {only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 1, less_than_or_equal_to: 3}
validates :local_team_id, :presence => true
validates :visiting_team_id, :presence => true
validates :stadium_id, :presence => true

def mydate_is_date?
    errors.add(:contructiondate, 'must be a valid date') if !mathdate.is_a?(Date)

end
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following validation

```
validates :local_team_id, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :mathdate}
validates :visiting_team_id, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :mathdate}
```

Comment: then You can select my answer as accepted answer and vote up :D thnx

Comment: done, I cant vote up because of my reputation, sorry